# iOS signing certificate issue

Tags: ios, xcode7.3

Anyone please help me to fix an issue on iOS signing identity issue.  When i archive the product, I am getting the error"you have a valid distribution certificate in the member centre. but it is not installed locally"
[image]

I downloaded the certificate from the member centre and installed locally.  But still I am getting the same issue.

I am able to solve the error by resetting the certificate from Xcode->preference->account->view details->signing identities->iOS distribution, all profiles associated with the certificate become inactive.  Again, I need to activate all in the member centre and download from Xcode->preference->account->view details->provisioning profiles->download all.

But the above step causes the problem to other developers as the certificate is been revoked.

How to solve this issue without resetting the certificate from Xcode?

FYI:  I am experiencing this issue in Xcode 7.3.

Comment: Apart from the certificate, you'd also need it's private key(.p12) file. Ask another developer to export from his keychain and send to you. you can then import it and sign the app.

Comment: Can you please send your keychain screenshot?

Comment: Careful! Do NOT press reset, it will generate a new Distribution-certificate without any warning. I have no idea how Apple can name such a risky process "Reset". You now may have duplicate Distribution-certificates in your keychain. Make sure that only the newest one is in there

Comment: I also come across this issue when I first upgrade to Xcode 7.3, but it started to work again later so I thought its an apple server side issue :) just saying,... anyway make sure that you have the private key in your key-chain.

Comment: [Refer this blog](https://edwardhackhands.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-distribution-certificate/) it will definitely help you to resolve. Still if you find it difficult refer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Comment: Thanks to all !! I was successfully able to sign the app by importing .p12 file.  @Vin You saved my day !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that you are using a Developer profile that is specific to you. If you have signed into an Apple Developer account (signed in through xcode's GUI) that is being shared by other team members then you will not be able to sign the code on your computer. Generating another p12 private key will cause the current p12 key assigned to that Developer profile to be revoked.

**If you are sharing an account**, go to Apple's Developer Center and add yourself as a team member. You will get an email to the address you add and then can follow the link to create an account. After you create your account generate a provisioning profile from the menu options and double click on the download once it completes.

Go back to Xcode and select the Xcode drop down menu. Choose Preferences from the list and highlight the profile you were using previously. Once its highlighted remove it by selecting the (-) option. Then click the (+) option and sign in to your new account. This should resolve your issue. Be sure to clean before building just in case.

**If you are already using a distinct account** that is only for you then you are receiving this error because you have changed machines and did not transfer the p12 key to your new device. You have two options now. **First option** is to use an external storage device or cloud service to transfer the p12 key to your new laptop. **Second option** is to generate a new p12 key from Apple's Developer portal. Double click on the download once it completes and it will be automatically added to Xcode.

Now return to Xcode.  Choose Preferences from the list and highlight the profile you were using previously. Once its highlighted remove it by selecting the (-) option. Then click the (+) option and sign in to your new account. This should resolve your issue.

**If you are still seeing this issue** you can take these additional steps to purge old caches that could be causing the issue. Open the Keychain Access program on your Macbook. Find the any old certificates that do not have private keys associated with them. Certificates without private keys (p12) will not have a grey disclosure arrow next to them. Delete these and try again.